# Model.objects return empty QuerySet on Django 1.7 and MongoEngine 0.9

Tags: django, mongoengine, mlab, pythonanywhere

Model.objects return empty QuerySet on Django 1.7 and MongoEngine 0.9
I am trying to connect to MongoLab with MongoEngine for my Django project. The authentication works, the Model is defined and I do not get any error or warning. However Mymodel.objects return an empty QuerySet in the View. Is there any known issue about that? I have tried many settings, however the result is the same.

I would be grateful if anybody could point me to a solution or where to look.

Ali